# Angular: How ca I show code (e.g. JSON) inside of a template?

Tags: angular

How can I show code (e.g. JSON) in an Angular Template?

```
<pre>
{ "bla":"bla" }
</pre>

<code>
{ "bla":"bla" }
</code>
```

Tried pre and code in the template section but both produce "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors...".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`json` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe).

```
<pre>{{ yourObjectWithJson | json }}</pre>
```

Just remember to import [`CommonModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) inside of `AppModule` (usually is there by default already).